# PHP 5.5.3 и JSON, магия

Tags: json, php, json_encode

Есть массив $res, данные не важны, это кусок метода.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo(json_encode(unserialize(serialize($res)))); // пустота
echo(json_encode($res)); // пустота
die(json_encode($res)); // пустота
var_dump($res); // выводит что нужно(если не учитывать, что нужен JSON)
```

Причём,

```
echo json_encode(array("dssdsd", "asdf")); // так всё работает
```

3 час бьюсь, спасайте! Подскажите, где я накосячил.

Проблема была в Юникоде, решил так:

```
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
$res[$key] = html_entity_decode(htmlentities($value, ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8"), 0, "UTF-8");
    }
```

Не уверен что это идеальный способ, но главное работает.

Comment: Обратите внимание, в доках пишут:

*"value - значение, которое будет закодировано. Может быть любого типа за исключением resource.

Функция работает только с кодированными в UTF-8 данными."*

Если это не поможет - `var_dump($res)` в студию!


UPD: Как вариант - смотреть, что выдает `var_dump(json_encode($res))`

Если `FALSE` - значит ошибка

Comment: присоединяюсь к @Johny → var_dump($res) в студию!

Comment: var_dump(res); // false;
Как лечить? P.S. Всё в UTF-8.
@Johny @Gedweb

Comment: var_dump(**res**) ? вы тут опечатались или в скрипте =)

давайте пойдем выше, откуда у вас $res берётся? (ответ в коде пожалуйста)

Comment: array(11) {
  ["[SLIDER_ELEMENTS]"]=>
  string(223) "          <div class="text-center item" id="sl_first">
           <br><h4>Ð</h4>
           L
          </div>
          <div class="text-center item" id="sl_second">
           <br><h4>a</h4>
           L
          </div>
"
это урезанный var_dump массива(парс полсотни утф-ных конфигов и слияние с такими же шаблонами). json_last_error() выдаёт 5.

Comment: @Gedweb json_last_error() говорит ошибка в кодировке, всё в utf8, под убунтой, что делать?

Comment: @saksmt, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, Ваше решение как ответ (для потомков).  
Если не можете отвечать на свои вопросы, то как комментарий.  
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @saksmt, Проверьте, чтоб страницы были в utf-8 **без BOM**.

Answer (score 1):

json_encode принимает к выводу только массив данных.
К примеру:
Этот вариант ничего не выведет.

```
$res = 'test';
echo json_encode($res);
```

А этот вариант выведет полученные данные.

```
$res = array('test');
echo json_encode($res);
```

Читайте внимательней документацию.

Comment: $res - одномерный массив.

Comment: Кстати, то что это массив написано в вопросе.